# Split pdf files from request and send the splitted pdf's as response without saving it locally Django/Python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pypdf

As mentioned in the title I have an API endpoint which receives a PDF file object from request. I need to split these PDF into multiple pdf's and send these split pdf's as response without saving any of these files locally using PYTHON inside a zip folder.

Thanks in Advance!!

I'm able to split and create zip if I save the files locally using pypdf2 but I just wanna know is there a way to split and put in a zip without saving locally.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should use pypdf instead of PyPDF2. I'm the maintainer of both and I deprecated PyPDF2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [streams](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/streaming-data.html). But, think about the memory consumption.